Library not loaded: CorePaymentCard SquareInApp
Library not loaded: @rpath/CorePaymentCard.framework/CorePaymentCard is the error that keeps popping up on me. I have used CocoaPods to install SquareInAppPaymentsSDK, and it builds, but as soon as it launches it crashes.
I have done all that needs to be done according to Square's documentation, including the Run Script Phase:
SETUP_SCRIPT=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}"/SquareInAppPaymentsSDK.framework/setup"
if [ -f "$SETUP_SCRIPT" ]; then
  "$SETUP_SCRIPT"
fi

Any ideas why I'm STILL getting this?
